# How should I name my handlebars?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, handlebars.js

In my emberjs + ruby on rails application I have a folder which I am keeping my handlebars.

```
 app/assets/javascript/templates
```

I am wondering what is the convention for naming files containing handlebars? Here are a few examples I can think of:

- `my_cool.handlebars`
- `myCool.handlebars`
- `my-cool.handlebars`

which one of these is actually cool?

Comment: The first would probably be the best match for the usual Rails convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best Convention Practice:

**Naming your variable:(If it is a class or object)** CamelCaps

**Naming your variable:(If it is an instance)** camelCase

**Naming your file:** snake_case.extension

**Naming your CSS classes or ids:** use-hyphen

PS: Ofcourse there is no such rule, but a good programming practice

Comment: awesome! I take your word for it. But I suggest trying to add a reference to your answer if you know of any. Thanks!

Comment: Reference to the first two in Ember: http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html

Comment: I don't have references to others but it's been a good practice, like in css we see the predefined properties/attributes are hyphen separated like "background-color", "font-type" etc so we can maintain uniformity by using the hyphen separated names...Not sure about naming file though, may be to separate from the other three styles?